# ios round number to int or .5

Tags: objective-c, ios

i have a list of numbers in a big long list imported from a CSV,

I need to consult the list after the user enters a number in a textfield,  so after the uses enters the number I need to take the number to the nearest integer or to x.5

for example

```
1;
1.5;
2;
```

and so on

so if the user enters 1.2, it will go to 1, and if user enters 1.45 goes to 1.5

so that is the general rule, but for a long set of numbers,

so how can i accomplish this?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Just do this:

```
x = round(x * 2.0) / 2.0;
```

This rounds `x` to the nearest multiple of 0.5.

Comment: Or just `x = round(x + 0.5);` which should be a cheaper calculation to perform (only one addition instead of an multiplication and a division)

Comment: @David: no, that will only round (up) to a whole number - the OP wants rounding to the nearest multiple of 0.5, AFAIUI.

Answer (score 1):

it'd look like something below in `Swift`

```
var valueToBechanged  = 3.45
// Casting the valueToBechanged to Double because it can be Float, Int etc
var roundedRating : Double = round(Double(valueToBechanged) * 2) / 2.0
```